# how to convert many .npz files to .mat files through for loop using python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, for-loop, scipy

i need to convert many .npz files to .mat file using python. my files are arranged like datafile_1.npz,datafile_2.npz...etc i want to convert these to datafile_1.mat,datafile_2.mat files etc.Insofar i wrote a code but getting error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'...why this error i am unable to understand.I hope somebody will help.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
import glob

filpath=glob.glob('./datafile_*.npz')

for file in filpath:
    #data = np.load('file',)
    scipy.io.savemat('filepath'+'.mat', mdict=file)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Develop your code in smaller steps.  Load one npz file, making sure you know how to read all of its arrays.  Then focus on writing all those to a mat.  Read the docs carefully.

Comment: @hpaulj, i found this as suitable script after reading docs....can you please suggest some better solution that will minimize the above mentioned error

Comment: When asking about an error, show the full code that produces it, along with traceback.  For a start `file` is the name of a file, so can't be source dictionary for `savemat`

Comment: line 834, in put_variables
    for name, var in mdict.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: how to solve this problem....give any idea to modify the code

Comment: Why do you do `data = np.load...` and then don't do anything with `data`?  Who or what told you to pass the filename `file` to `savemat`?  Don't just follow some script.  Without understanding what's going on, any little mistake will be a mystery.  Pay attention to what each variable is - file name (string), dictionary, array, open-file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With a `npz` that I have from an earlier SO:

```
In [491]: data = np.load('test.npz')                                                                 
In [492]: list(data.keys())                                                                          
Out[492]: ['arr_0', 'arr_1', 'arr_2']
In [493]: data['arr_0']                                                                              
Out[493]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
In [494]: data['arr_1']                                                                              
Out[494]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
In [495]: data['arr_2']                                                                              
Out[495]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

`data` is a `dict` like object.  So it can actually be passed as the `mdict` parameter to `savemat` (which also expects a dict):

```
In [496]: io.savemat('data.dat', data)
```

test the save:

```
In [497]: io.loadmat('data.dat')                                                                     
Out[497]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Sun Aug  2 17:16:18 2020',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'arr_0': array([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]),
 'arr_1': array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]),
 'arr_2': array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])}
```

alternatively we could make our own dict

```
In [498]: io.savemat('data.dat', mdict={'x':data['arr_0'], 'y':data['arr_1']})                       
In [499]: io.loadmat('data.dat')                                                                     
Out[499]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Sun Aug  2 17:19:06 2020',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'x': array([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]),
 'y': array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])}
```

The key is to understand that `np.load` for an `npz` returns `dict`, from which we can load actual arrays.  This `dict` is not itself the data.  Likewise `savemat` expects a `dict` of arrays.  Since both work with dicts, we don't have to explicitly load the arrays.